# arrangement of a group of people.

Tags: permutations

The no. of ways in which 4 particular persons A,B,C,D and 6 other persons can stand in a queue so that A always stands before B, B before C and C before D is ?

My try: since A B C D always have to stand together taking them as one, we get, 7! Ans

Is this correct?. Help needed.

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't state that A, B, C, and D stand together, only that A is before B (there may be people in between), and B before C, and C before D.

Hint: Consider all $10!$ ways of lining up 10 people. What fraction of them have A before B, B before C, and C before D?

Answer (score 2):

First, choose $4$ out of $10$ places for the persons $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. This can be done in $n_1={10\choose4}=\frac{10!}{4!(10-4)!}$ ways.

Then, distribute the other persons into the remaining $6$ places. This can be done in $n_2=6!$ ways.

Finally, by the principle of multiplication, the answer is given by $n_1n_2=\frac{10!}{4!}$.

Comment: Also, the answer has to be $\dfrac{10!}{4!}$ because, if the $10!$ arrangements are equally likely, the probability of $A,B,C,D$ being in that particular order is $\dfrac1{4!}$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "stand before."  If you take it to mean *immediately* before, then your $7!$ is correct.  But if it just means that $A$ is somewhere ahead of $B$, etc., then you get a different answer.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Got it... thanks